# Como pasar de String a Double sin perder precisión en los decimales - Java

Tags: java

Quiero pasar un número decimal que está en una variable de tipo String a una de tipo Double, pero antes aplicando un formato concreto con DecimalFormat (import java.Text.DecimalFormat) para que tenga siempre 3 decimales. Al realizar la conversión siempre me pierde decimales, más exactamente los decimales que son 0 a la derecha.

¿Sabéis como realizar esta conversión sin perder esa precisión?

Yo he encontrado que utilizando el tipo BigDecimal se soluciona, pero me gustaría realizar esta conversión sin utilizarlo.

Saludos,

---

Por ejemplo:

```
Double d = 0.85;   // 0.85
DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
String s = mf.format(d); // "0,850"

s = s.replace(',', '.'); // "0.850"

double conv = Double.parseDouble(s); //0.85

//Como pasar del String s = "0.850" -> Double = 0.850?
```

Comment: Simple: no uses `Double`, utiliza `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La conversión que realizas es correcta:

```
double conv = Double.parseDouble(s); //0.85
```

No veo la necesidad de agregar los decimales que son cero después del punto decimal en un valor de tipo doble.

Si tienes decimales en 0 después del punto decimal es como si no existieran por lo tanto:

```
 if(0.850 == 0.85){
            System.out.println("Esto es lo mismo!");
   }
```

Si definimos una variable con decimales a la derecha que son ceros, después del punto decimal:

```
double va = 0.8500000000000;
```

el valor sera siempre `0.85`

Si definimos una variable con decimales a la derecha y existe un numero que no es cero, después del punto decimal:

```
double va = 0.8500000000001;
```

entonces el valor sería `0.8500000000001`

#### Si ùnicamente deseas imprimir en pantalla el valor y asegurar tener todos los decimales puedes usar **[setMinimumFractionDigits()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int))**

```
  Double d = 0.85;   // 0.85
        DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        mf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        String s = mf.format(d);
```

Aquí tendrás un valor: `0.850`

Comment: gracias por tu comentario! Pero el problema es que no es para calcular ningún valor, ya que así esos 0 no son necesarios, sino que es para imprimir por pantalla ese 0.85 en este formato 0.850. Para dar formato utilizo DecimalFormat, pero cuando tengo el String s = "0.850", al pasar a Double, me elimina el 0 final y no se como realizar esta conversión manteniendo este último decimal.

Comment: @jmgc1982 Si necesitas imprimirlo puedes hacerlo en formato string sin convertirlo a doble, y asegurar mostrar minimo 3 digitos fraccionales, con setMinimumFractionDigits(3); ve mi actualización.

Comment: Muy interesante el método setMinimumFractionDigits(), no lo conocia, pero es que al final debe ser un Double, ya que ese valor lo retorna el método que contiene el código y este método retorna un Double.

Comment: ya lo he solucionado! En esta clase había un método creado que me pasaba a String y así podía realizar un formateo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Elenasys!!!

Comment: Hola, también podías haber usado la función printf. 
Aquí estoy imprimiendo la variable con 20 decimales.

    `double valor = 0.5;`  
    `System.out.printf("%.20f %n", valor);`

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Sabéis como realizar esta conversión sin perder esa precisión?

En realidad, no existe ningún tal método, porque hay un gran problema:

- El tipo `double` es codificado en **binario**.

Por ejemplo, usando [la calculadora de este sitio](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/), el numeral decimal 0.850 corresponde a este numeral binario:

```
0.11011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110...
```

Los puntos suspensivos indican que este numeral se repite (igual a como 1/3 = 0.33333...).  Cuando quitamos los puntos suspensivos y ponemos el numeral binario en esa página para la conversión de vuelta a decimal, obtenemos:

```
0.8499999999999999999132638262011596452794037759304046630859375
```

0.850 tiene tres dígitos en decimal, pero infinitamente muchos en binario.  Lo cual quiere decir que cuando escribimos `double x = 0.850` el valor de `x` no es en realidad 0.850, sino un número **cercano** a 0.850, del cual no podemos decir si originalmente se escribió como 0.85, 0.850 or 0.8500.

Si las aproximaciones inherentes en el tipo `double` so inaceptables para alguna aplicación donde hace falta representar numerales decimales de manera precisa, hay que usar `BigDecimal`.